# Handmade plant timelapse, how can I modify the general frame, zoom?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to create a single timelapse with several growing plant species (when they have decided to germinate...).

I have combined my pictures with the following command line (I am on xubuntu):

```
ffmpeg -framerate 10 -pattern_type glob -i '*.JPG' -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p plantes.mp4
```

The general frame we have selected to begin with is too large (there is an empty space on the top, about half of each image).

Can I cut the upper part of each picture and how?

Is it possible to zoom on the base of the pictures, where the growing plants are present?

Comment: This might be better asked on photo.stackexchange.com. Even if it's about photo editing software use, they might know it better than people on this site.

Comment: @computercarguy The question is on topic here and can be answered  by members of this community. Please only suggest other sites if questions are clearly off topic, or if you add a note that users should not double-post their questions, but instead can flag the post for moderator attention to get it migrated.

Comment: @slhck, I've suggested migration before and was told it's not likely, due to the OP, commentors, and answerers not existing on the other site and not wanting an account created for them on that site. I also said "might", as in "the OP should check it out at least". Glad to know I can always be wrong in every situation.

Comment: @computercarguy I know you were trying to be helpful and get the OP a good answer, and you were not wrong to do that. However, we sometimes have problems with new users feeling pushed away from a community they've just decided to join, or creating duplicate questions, etc. Particularly in this case, there was already a solution posted, so no real reason to migrate a question (it'd make sense to migrate after a few days if there are no answers), hence my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Basic syntax is

```
ffmpeg -framerate 10 -pattern_type glob -i '*.JPG' -vf 'crop=iw/2:ih/2:iw/4:ih/2,scale=iw*2:-2' -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p plantes.mp4
```

This will keep the bottom centre of the frame, and rescale it to original size.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the modification is massive! 
I have to tune it, I guess through the 'crop' and 'scale' options.
Best / Sophie